# What does a string like 1e-6+6.0459e-1 mean in the context of a vertical axis label in a matplotlib plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a Python code that gives me plot like this one (made by matplotlib):

[image]

the mean value is about 0.6065

Then I change a parameter and, starting from a certain value, matplotlib automatically add a string like `1e-6+6.0459e-1` to the vertical axis:

[image]

What does it mean?
Maybe that there is a "reference" y-value at `+6.0459e-1` and there is an oscillation peak to peak of about 5e-6?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that each number `y` on the vertical axis is *actually* `y * 10**-6 + 6.0459 * 10**-1`.

In other words, the sine curve is *basically* the flat line `6.0459 * 10**-1` (a.k.a. `0.60459`) that has some additive "noise" (the sine curve) of the order of `10**-6`, which is a very small number.

You can force a more legible scale with something like [`plt.ylim(0.604, 0.605)`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylim.html).

---

I think this is documented in the "Offset notation and scientific notation" section of the [documentation for `matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html?highlight=formatter#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter):

> Offset notation and scientific notation look quite similar at first sight. Both split some information from the formatted tick values and display it at the end of the axis.
>
> - The scientific notation splits up the order of magnitude, i.e. a multiplicative scaling factor, e.g. `1e6`.
> - The offset notation separates an additive constant, e.g. `+1e6`. The offset notation label is always prefixed with a `+` or `-` sign and is thus distinguishable from the order of magnitude label.

Thus, in `1e-6+6.0459e-1`:

- `1e-6` is the order of magnitude in scientific notation
- `+6.0459e-1` is the offset in scientific notation

Comment: Thank you! Is that documented somewhere?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson, I think I finally found it. Please see updated answer

Comment: thank you very much for your help! Frankly speaking, I personally find the "offset notation" not so immediately comprehensible... I've never seen it in a book or in a a paper...